# force push to another remote branch using husky hook

Tags: git, shell

I would like to run

```
git push origin --force CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME:sandbox
```

in a pre-push hook.

How do I get

```
CURRENT_BRANCH_NAME
```

as part of the above command?

I understand I can have `git branch --show-current` to return the current branch name. Just not sure how to use its output with the above-mentioned git command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll answer the question you actually asked:

- To get the current branch name, use `git branch --show-current` or `git symbolic-ref --short HEAD` or `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.  **Note that these three commands do slightly different things!**  See details below.
- In POSIX-compatible shells, to substitute the output of a command in place inside another command as an argument, use either backquotes or `$(` and `)`.  I prefer the `$(...)` sequence as it nests properly: that is, you can put another `$(...)` inside the `$(...)` and it Just Works since parentheses nest.  This is not true of backquotes (they can be made to work but it is trickier).

Next, I'll note that you should not bother to do this.  The reason is simple: you have to pick one of the above three items and two of them are probably wrong, *and* this is all unnecessary.  Simply use:

```
git push --force origin HEAD:sandbox
```

or, for strict correctness in the case where two of the items are probably wrong:

```
git push --force origin HEAD:refs/heads/sandbox
```

This variant uses a *fully qualified* reference, `refs/heads/sandbox`, to refer to the *branch name* `sandbox` in the remote Git, regardless of the result of an attempt to turn `HEAD` into a Git commit hash ID.

#### Why this works

The `git push` command pushes *commits* (not files, not branches, just commits and other supporting Git objects) to the other Git.  Once the commits (and/or other supporting Git objects) have made it *to* that other Git and are ready to be used there, *then* `git push` *ends* by asking (non-forced push) or commanding (forced push) the other Git to create, delete, or update some name(s) in *their* repository.

To achieve this sequence of events, `git push` needs:

- the raw hash ID(s) of some commit(s) and/or other supporting Git objects it should send if / as needed;
- the *names* it should ask / command the other Git to set or delete, along with the operation to do (set vs delete); and
- the force flag (which can be a simple off/on, or one of the more complicated "with lease" style options).

Your Git—your software, sending from your repository, to the other Git that's software receiving into a target repository—gets these three items from:

- flags like `--force` or the `+` in `+HEAD:refs/heads/sandbox` or the `--delete` in `git push --delete`, which go in the obvious positions;
- for the raw hash ID(s) that should be *sent*, from the *left side* of the `src:dst` pair;
- for the *name to update*, from the *right side* of this same pair.

Git calls the pair itself, with or without the optional `+` force flag, a *refspec*.  So `feature:sandbox` is a refspec, and `HEAD:sandbox` is also a refspec.  In fact, even the degenerate form:

```
git push origin main
```

for instance, uses a refspec: it's just one in which the colon is missing, so that you provide only a *`src`* part.  This is a *partial* refspec and in this case, Git uses the *same name* for the target as you supplied for the source (for `git push` that is—while `git fetch` also works with refspecs, its treatment of partial refspecs is different).

Since you already plan to use a *full* refspec, with the colon in it, the item on the left is not required to be a *name*.  The *name* that your Git will send to the other Git comes from the right hand side of the refspec.

Now, there's a small hitch here: how does the sending Git (i.e., yours) know whether to ask the receiving Git to set a *branch name* (`refs/heads/moo`), or a *tag* name (`refs/tags/moo`), or perhaps some other kind of name (`refs/for/moo` for Gerrit for instance) if you give your Git an *unqualified* name like `moo`?  The answer is that your Git and/or their Git will do their best to *guess* which kind of name you mean, but in general, when you are doing this—providing a full *refspec*, that is—it's wise to provide a full *ref* on the right, so that you know for sure what you intend to ask the other Git to set (or delete).  This is especially true from scripts, which may operate without a human overseer.

#### Hence there is a general rule here

When you, as a human, are running:

```
git push origin feature3 v1.2
```

you know that `feature3` is your own local branch name, and `v1.2` is your own local tag name, so you know that this is really `refs/heads/feature3:refs/heads/feature3` and `refs/tags/v1.2:refs/tags/v1.2`.  But in *scripts*, which are generally write-once run-many-times, it's wiser to be explicit.

#### Coda: the three different commands

Git has two "modes" for HEAD: *attached* and *detached*.  (Note: Git calls the latter *detached HEAD mode;* I made up the name *attached HEAD mode* as the obvious counterpart, but it's not officially a Git name.)  In the attached-HEAD mode, the name `HEAD` is a *symbolic reference* to a *branch name*.<sup>1</sup>  In the *detached* mode, however, `HEAD` holds a raw commit hash ID.

The command `git branch --show-current` will show the name to which `HEAD` is attached when you are in attached-HEAD mode, but will *silently print nothing and exit with a successful status* when you are in detached-HEAD mode.

The command `git symbolic-ref HEAD` prints the full name of the branch to which `HEAD` is attached when in attached-HEAD mode, and produces *an error message, no standard output, and a nonzero exit code* when in detached-HEAD mode.  It prints the short version of the branch name with `--short` but still produces the same no-output-but-error-instead when detached.

The command `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` prints the shortened name of the current branch when in attached-HEAD mode, and prints the word `HEAD` when in detached-HEAD mode.

There's one more mode worthy of mention here, although it's quite rare: when you are on an "orphan" or "unborn" branch (Git uses both terms to refer to this state), the name `HEAD` is a symbolic ref to a branch name that does not exist.  In *this* state, `git branch --show-current` and `git symbolic-ref HEAD` both succeed (and print the nonexistent branch name), but `git rev-parse --abbrev-rev HEAD` fails.

To test which mode you're in and get the commit hash ID:

```
detached=false unborn=false
branch=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null) || detached=true
if ! $detached; then
    git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD >/dev/null || unborn=true
fi
```

After executing these five lines, `$detached` holds whether `HEAD` is detached (as a simple boolean result), `$branch` holds the branch name if `HEAD` is not detached, and `$unborn` contains the result of testing whether there is currently a commit, or making a new commit will create the current branch.  (The need for `$unborn` is rare.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In ancient, primeval Git, this was implemented with symlinks: `ln -s refs/heads/master HEAD` for instance.  Git had to drop this particular shortcut when it was ported to Windows, which lacked symlinks.